# NaN when parsing value returned by parseInt() and toLocaleString Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```
alert(parseInt(new Date().toLocaleString('es', {month:'numeric'})));
```

This code always return 'NaN' on IE

why is this?

how can i solved only using vanilla javascript.

Comment: What is it you actually want to do?

Comment: Only modern browsers (including IE11) support locale and options parameters, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: Which version of IE? Are you sure the call is compatible with the version of IE that you are using?

Comment: i wanth to get the current month number

Comment: To get the current "month number": `(new Date().getMonth()) + 1`. Presumably `new Date().toLocaleString('es', {month:'numeric'})` does not return a string that starts with a digit, so `parseInt` returns `NaN`.

Comment: im using Internet Explorer 11

Comment: Still interesting that this won't work. I can reproduce it in IE11. The string *looks* like `"10"` but when compared with `"10"` yields false.

Comment: @Andrew: What does `.length` return?

Comment: @FelixKling: `3`, with `[0] === ""`

Comment: Thanks i solve my problem using 'new Date().getMonth()'

Comment: I think the character is a [Left-to-right mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) upon further inspection, in case anyone is interested... And here's an explanation of what's going on: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25574963/497356

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var date = new Date();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
```

This should work for you to get the month.