# Internet Explorer Returning Wrong Length of String

Tags: javascript, locale, internet-explorer-11, string-length

I've ran into a possible bug with IE where calling the JavaScript .`length` function returns a value that is off by 1 if/when the string was derived from `.toLocaleString()`.

```
var d = new Date();
var locale = navigator.language;
var month = d.toLocaleString(locale, { month: "long"});
// month.length will return the length of the month string +1 
//(eg: if month = "March", month.length will return 6.)
```

Interestingly, the code example of above will return true (in IE) for the following: **(month[0] should be "M")**

```
month[0] == "";
month[1] == "M";
month[2] == "a";
month[3] == "r";
month[4] == "c";
month[5] == "h";
```

In my particular case, this is causing a problem where I need to `.slice()` the month. Example: If the month is March, then IE will return "Ma" for `month.slice(0,3)` instead of "Mar".

Is this a known bug with IE? Is there a fix and/or workaround for this problem?

Run this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gs3p55r6/) in IE and Chrome/Firefox/Safari and notice how the `month.length` is wrong in IE.

**My Environment:**

> OS: Win Server 2012 R2
>
> IE Version: 11.0.9600.18231 (Update Versions: 11.0.29)
>
> Locale: English/US

Comment: Give us your OS, current locale and browser version build.

Comment: That's bizarre. I get the same result. Tried .trim(), and .replace(/\s+/, "") , but still showing extra blank character at beginning

Comment: What is the result of `month.charCodeAt(0)`?

Comment: @apsillers - month.charCodeAt(0) returns 8206

Comment: @Knu - updated OP with requested info

Comment: Character 8206 is the control character that states that the text should be left to right.

Comment: BTW if you're doing a slice on a `toLocaleString` result you're probably Doing It Wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, I stumbled upon this post [toLocaleDateString error in IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413757/tolocaledatestring-changes-in-ie11)

It appears it is caused by the toLocaleDateString function added extra LTR and RTL characters in IE11. One of the comments gave a regex replace function that is working for me.

```
month.replace(/[^ -~]/g,'');
```

Try adding that after you perform the `.toLocaleDateString()` and it should work. It worked for me.

Just another reason for us to despise IE.

Comment: Also want to add [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25574963/ies-tolocalestring-has-strange-characters-in-results) as related for future readers.

Comment: "This is by design so the output text will flow properly when concatenated with other text."

Comment: Thank you so much ! I used a regex to check the date after a call to toLocaleDateString()
and did not undestand why it won't work on IE11 -_-