# Javascript String Length Incorrect

Tags: javascript

I am trying to debug a really strange string length problem in Internet Explorer 11.

I cannot work out why it is telling me that the string "01/03/2017" has a length of 15?

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong please?

[image]

Here is the function

```
function stringToUKDate(strDate) {
debugger;
newDate = strDate.trim().substr(0, 10);
var dateSplit = newDate.split("/");
var newDate = new Date(dateSplit[2], dateSplit[1] - 1, dateSplit[0], 0, 0, 0);
// return the new date
return newDate;
}
```

> encodeURIComponent(strDate) gives me
>   %E2%80%8E01%E2%80%8E%2F%E2%80%8E02%E2%80%8E%2F%E2%80%8E2017

Comment: What does `encodeURIComponent(strDate)` give you…?

Comment: Guess is, that there are some non-printable characters within the string.

Comment: as it's a "Date" string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36225603/internet-explorer-returning-wrong-length-of-string

Comment: "Here is the function" — An [mcve] needs to be complete. You haven't shown us what input you are providing to the function.

Comment: encodeURIComponent(strDate) gives me %E2%80%8E01%E2%80%8E%2F%E2%80%8E02%E2%80%8E%2F%E2%80%8E2017

Comment: Yup, that confirms that it's @Roman's duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I think that issue come from your type, maybe the conversion adds some chars (maybe non-breaking spaces or just not display chars but are counted...)
try the date format or a tostring