# Getting %FD in resulting string when using Date.toLocaleString in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, http-post

I was looking for a way to get the month name and day-of-week name from a `Date` object in javascript and came across this post: [Get month name from Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643320/get-month-name-from-date) where David Storey pointed to the `date.toLocaleString()` method.  At first it looked like this was working great.  I could do something like this to get the month name without having to define an array:

```
var someDate = new Date(2018, 8, 28);
var locale = "en-us"
var month = someDate.toLocaleString(locale, { month: "short" }).toLowerCase();
```

that would give me a result of `aug` in the month variable. But I noticed a problem with this.  Ultimately I was dropping the month and day-of-week values into hidden form fields that would get posted with the form.  When the form posted I wasn't getting the expected values.  For example, looking at the posted value for the month field, instead of `aug` I was getting `%FDaug`, and the same was true for the day-of-week value.  But if I checked the values in the debugger prior to posting, they looked correct.  I don't know where the `%FD` was coming from but it means I can't use this method unless there is some way to trim that off first.  I looked at documentation for the function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) but didn't see anything there related to this issue.

For now I'm back to using an array of month and day names and doing a lookup to get those.  Anyone know why that extra ascii character is introduced when using `Date.toLocaleString`?

Here are screenshots from the browser debugger, I've tried this in IE, Edge, and Chrome.  Chrome appears to be ok, but IE and Edge have this behavior.  I haven't tried Firefox

the values before posting...
[image: debugger variables are ok]

the posted values...

[image: posted values are wrong]

Comment: I think you're going to have to define an array or trim these chars off based on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25574963/ies-tolocalestring-has-strange-characters-in-results

I'd suggest moment.js to handle dates if you can justify adding a dep for just dates: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: @MichaelCurry thank you for the suggestion.  I went with the array option since I don't need to deal with different locales and didn't want to bring in a new library just for this.